# In the Ramayan, Did Lord Parsuram Knew that Lord rama is Visnu avatar?

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, rama, parashurama

As, I know that, when Lord Rama broke the Shiva-Bow,and for that reason Lord Parsuram came to the hall and challenge to the Lord Rama to war with him?Did they don't know each-other before that incidence they both are Visnu avatar ? anyone have some idea about it?.

Comment: You might be interested in the answer to a related question here:http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7754/anshavatar-and-purnavatar-are-there-different-types-of-avatars/12023#12023

Comment: Thanks for your reply brother, But it is totally different, my confusion is lord parsuram knew that lord rama is Vishnu avatar, before challenging him..?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Similar questions (see [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9188/2995) and [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10297/2995)) were already asked regarding Rama, so I'd suggest to make this a question just about Parashurama. Else it might be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @sv now is it ok ?..

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I may have misunderstood your question - so what you want to know is "Before he met Rama, did Parashurama know that Rama is a Vishnu avatar?"

Comment: @sv My question is like mention in description, when Lord Rama broke the Shiv-Dhanus, so, that's why Lord Parsuram was very angry and go to the hall, and challenge to Lord rama for war, so, I am confusing whether lord pursuram didn't knew that Lord Rama is also incarnation of Lord Vishnu and also vice versa

Comment: @ShreeKrishna See if [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11943/2995) answers your question.

Comment: You may be interested in my answer here.. http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11558/why-couldnt-parashurama-recognize-rama-as-vishnus-avatar-during-the-breaking-o/11561#11561

Comment: @Tezz: Thanks Tezz, you are awesome , Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of avataras - purna & avesha . [Source](http://veda.wikidot.com/avatara)

- purna avatara (Rama) - Lord himself
- avesha avatara : These itself are of 2 types :
  Parashurama (all powers of Lord endowed within a jivatma)
  Kartaviryarjuna (some powers of Lord endowed within a jivatma)

These are in decreasing order of shakti, so Rama defeated Parashuram who defeated Kartiviryarjuna.

So, yes, Parashurama realized that Rama was a purna avatar after he grabbed vishnu dhanus from him, and offered all his tapas to Rama realizing that his time was over, then went for more penance in mountains.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: @ram Do you have any source?. it is not perfect answer.

Comment: @ram, please remove your answer othewise you will get downvotes.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna, here is one [source](http://veda.wikidot.com/avatara). but that is not my main source, it is the best I could find on the internet. If you know tamil, you can listen to Velukkudi Krishnan swamin's Dashavatara upanyasam, where he explains the types of avataras.